# If bash pipeline commands run in subshell, why echo command can access the non-exported variables?

Tags: linux, bash, pipeline

Bash manual says "Each command in a pipeline is executed as a separate process (i.e., in a subshell)". I test two simple commands.

#### Scene 1

```
cd /home/work
str=hello
echo $str | tee a.log
```

It outputs:

```
hello
```

It seems that echo command is not executed in a subshell, as it can access the non-exported variable `$str`.

#### Scene 2

```
cd /home/work
cd src | pwd
pwd
```

It outputs:

```
/home/work
```

Is looks like cd command is executed in a subshell, as it doesn't affect the working directory of original shello.

Can anyone explain why the behaviors are not consistent?

Answer (score 0):

> Can anyone explain why the behaviors are not consistent?

Well, because this is how it was designed. A "subshell" inherits the whole context, not only exported variables.

> Bash manual says "Each command in a pipeline is executed as a separate process (i.e., in a subshell)"

[Bsah manual is available here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html). The sentence you are mentioning literally has a link to solve the mystery:

> Each command in a pipeline is executed in its own subshell, which is a separate process (see Command Execution Environment).

Then you can check the "Command Execution Environment", from it (emphasis mine):

> The shell has an execution environment, which consists of the following:
>
> - ...
> - shell parameters that are set by variable assignment ...
> - ...
>
> ...
>
> Command substitution, commands grouped with parentheses, and asynchronous commands are invoked in **a subshell environment** that **is a duplicate of the shell environment**, ....

A subshell has **all** the environment (well, except traps). On the other hand commands:

> When a simple command other than a builtin or shell function is to be executed, it is invoked in a separate execution environment that consists of the following. ....
>
> - ...
> - shell variables and functions marked for export, ...

> If bash pipeline commands run in subshell, why echo command can access the non-exported variables?

Because a subshell inherits the parent environment, including all the non-exported variables.